# Cropping a numpy.ndArray throws - ValueError: cannot write empty image as JPEG

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to crop a numpy array image into smaller tiles and saving them: but when i try to save the tile i get an error that the image is empty.

My script takes into account excess pixels that does not reach the tile size and spread it out to the borders.

```
print("Slicing Image.")

path = 'Sliced/'
filename= 'sample_svs_2_'
img = tif.imread('sample_svs_2.svs')
print(type(img)) 
print(img.shape) 

#This works, proving that 
#this method of saving is valid
data = im.fromarray(img)
data.save('Sliced/sample.jpg') 


#depth, height, width  = img.shape
height, width, depth = img.shape
tilesize = 256

print("Height: ", height)
print("Width: ", width)
print("Depth: ", depth)

leftExcessPixels = int((width%tilesize)/2)
topExcessPixels = int((height%tilesize)/2)
XNumberOfTiles = int(width/tilesize)
YNumberOfTiles = int(height/tilesize)

print('Left Excess Pixels: ' + str(leftExcessPixels) )
print('Top Excess Pixels: ' + str(topExcessPixels) )

print('Number of X tiles: ' + str(XNumberOfTiles))
print('Number of Y tiles: ' + str(YNumberOfTiles))

for y in range(YNumberOfTiles):
    for x in range(XNumberOfTiles):
        XStart = (leftExcessPixels + (tilesize * x))
        YStart = (topExcessPixels + (tilesize * y))
        XEnd = XStart + tilesize
        YEnd = YStart + tilesize
        croppedImage = img[XStart:YStart, XEnd:YEnd] 
        data = im.fromarray(croppedImage)
        data.save('Sliced/sample_x' + str(x) + '_y' + str(y) + '.jpg')
```

Terminal Output:

```
Slicing Image.
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(13271, 19992, 3)
Height:  13271
Width:  19992
Depth:  3
Left Excess Pixels: 12
Top Excess Pixels: 107
Number of X tiles: 78
Number of Y tiles: 51
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\fileImageSlicer.py", line 72, in <module>
    sliceImage()
  File "c:\fileImageSlicer.py", line 52, in sliceImage
    data.save('Sliced/sample_x' + str(x) + '_y' + str(y) + '.jpg')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2439, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\miniconda3\Lib\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 647, in _save
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: cannot write empty image as JPEG
```

What might i be doing wrong? one thing i totally ignored is the image being read has a z-dimension (depth?) im not sure why an image has a depth (maybe for color? RGB) , and im not sure how to use that..

Comment: Shouldn't the `croppedImage` be `croppedImage = img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd]` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely your absolutely right, i jumbled up the format for the coordinates. Works fine now.. Also do i have to do anything on that z axis?

Comment: I think no, this is handled automatically. cropped images will have shape `(256, 256, 3)`. I'll write an answer so you can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in line:

```py
croppedImage = img[XStart:YStart, XEnd:YEnd]
```

The correct way of slicing the array should be:

```py
croppedImage = img[YStart:YEnd, XStart:XEnd]
```

That way each of the cropped images have shape `(256, 256, 3)`